# How can I create tabbed JQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I created a pop up dialog when I click on an image : 
http://fewste.ps/blueimp-jQuery-Image-Gallery/

but how can I add tabs to the pop up window ???

Answer (score 0):

Put your tabs inside a div then use a modal plugin which supports inline , and call for that div